# iOS Creating a file in the bundle using C++ not working on ios 6

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, ofstream

If i create a file in the simulator i am successfull with:

```
const char* testFile = "Test.java";
ofstream createTest;
createTest.open(testFile);
createTest << [CodeView.text UTF8String] ;
createTest.close();
```

On iOS 5.0 this works fine, at least in the simulator but on my upgraded version of xcode (ios 6.1)this just throws me:

```
 libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

How do i bypass this error, (is there maybe a way to load /write to an existing file in a folder using c++?)

Comment: "the bundle" means the app bundle?

Answer (score 0):

The application bundle on iOS is read-only.

Comment: @DavidKarlsson Yes, it is in iOS 1.0, 1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 2.0, 2.0.1, etc. up to 6.1.3, you get it?

Comment: @DavidKarlsson "The simulator" is the keyword. Simulator != device. The kernel/sandbox of OS X is much more permissive than that of iOS, therefore you can do stuff on the simulator that fails on the device.